# python, datetime.date: difference between two days

Tags: python

I'm playing around with 2  objects {@link http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date}

I would like to calculate all the days between them, assuming that date 1 >= date 2, and print them out. Here is an example what I would like to achieve. But I don't think this is efficient at all. Is there a better way to do this?

```
# i think +2 because this calc gives only days between the two days, 
# i would like to include them
daysDiff = (dateTo - dateFrom).days + 2

while (daysDiff > 0):
     rptDate = dateFrom.today() - timedelta(days=daysDiff)
     print rptDate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
     daysDiff -= 1
```

Comment: This about the best you can do.  What's inefficient?  What don't you like?

Comment: You might want to mark Ben James' answer as your preferred answer by clicking the check mark below the answer's votes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see this as particularly inefficient, but you could make it slightly cleaner without the while loop:

```
delta = dateTo - dateFrom

for delta_day in range(0, delta.days+1): # Or use xrange in Python 2.x
    print dateFrom + datetime.timedelta(delta_day)
```

(Also, notice how printing or using `str` on a `date` produces that `'%Y-%m-%d'` format for you for free)

It might be inefficient, however, to do it this way if you were creating a long list of days in one go instead of just printing, for example:

```
[dateFrom + datetime.timedelta(delta_day) for delta_day in range(0, delta.days+1)]
```

This could easily be rectified by creating a generator instead of a list. Either replace `[...]` with `(...)` in the above example, or:

```
def gen_days_inclusive(start_date, end_date):
    delta_days = (end_date - start_date).days
    for day in xrange(delta_days + 1):
        yield start_date + datetime.timedelta(day)
```

Whichever suits your syntax palate better.

Comment: Thank you Ben =) I will absolutely use your advice. I just thought there might be a lib that I can't find that does cal/date/datetime such transformation without manual traversing.

Comment: Ben, time and time again i find this very useful! ty